# Masking an SVGPattern

Tags: svg, mask

fiIs it possible to Mask an SVGPattern?

I've made the following SVG, but I can't get the mask to work.
Or should I be using clipPath?

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="160px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 160 600" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="circlePattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"
             viewBox="0 0 10 10" fill="blue" >
      <circle cx='4' cy='4' r='4'/>
    </pattern> 
    <clipPath id="clipPath" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" fill="white" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <!-- Outline the drawing area in blue -->
  <g id="box">
  <rect fill="url(#circlePattern)" width="160" height="600" clip-path="url(#clipPath)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

UPDATE: (I would like to use this complex path)

I can't seem to use this path to create the mask/clipPath

```
    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M9.35,37.5c4.1,2.467,8.566,3.7,13.4,3.7
        c7.667,0,13.783-2.05,18.35-6.15c5.066-4.566,7.6-11.167,7.6-19.8c0-5.7-2.367-12.133-7.1-19.3c-4.1-6.267-9.7-12.684-16.8-19.25
        c-5.133-4.8-10.383-8.983-15.75-12.55c-2.4-1.6-3.883-2.6-4.45-3c-1.733-1.033-3.267-1.8-4.6-2.3h-0.05c-1.3,0.5-2.8,1.267-4.5,2.3
        c-0.633,0.434-2.133,1.417-4.5,2.95c-5.467,3.667-10.867,8-16.2,13c-6.967,6.566-12.467,12.917-16.5,19.05
        c-4.633,7.1-6.95,13.467-6.95,19.1c0,8.633,2.534,15.233,7.6,19.8c4.567,4.1,10.684,6.15,18.35,6.15c4.833,0,9.3-1.233,13.4-3.7
        c4-2.367,7.1-5.6,9.3-9.7C2.25,31.9,5.383,35.133,9.35,37.5z"/>
```

Comment: Note that `maskUnits` on a <clipPath> element won't have any effect, try `clipPathUnits` instead? See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#ClipPathElementClipPathUnitsAttribute for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mask rect has no fill specified so it will use the default which is black i.e. i.e. rgba(0, 0, 0, 1). So the luminance of the mask is 0 everywhere and you see nothing.

If you change the fill on the mask `<rect>` to `fill="white"` you'll see the mask act as a clip which would seem to be what you're looking for. Other colours like "orange" or "blue" as they have a luminance which is neither 0 nor 1 will give you an intermediate effect.

clipPaths clip a shape to a boundary. Masks generally modify colours, you *can* use them to clip by having a white mask but if all you want is to clip something then a clipPath is faster.

clipPaths and masks can contain any graphics element including a path.

Comment: Right so clipPaths for _solid_ shapes? and Masks for things with luminance.

Does clipPath only work with Circles, Rects, and Polygons?

How about a path?

Comment: clipPaths to clip to a bounary. You can use a path.